# JPA findBy Query creation plus custom parameter

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.2.6` with `JPA` and `PostgreSQL DBMS`.

Suppose I have the `entity` **Nation** as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "nation")
public class Nazione {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String nome;
  private Boolean active;
}
```

Than I have the `Repository`:

```
@Repository
public interface NazioneRepository extends JpaRepository<Nazione, Integer> {
  public List<Nazione> findByActiveTrue();
}
```

With `JPA Query Creation` the method `findByActiveTrue()` retrieve all **Nation** with `active` set to `true`.

I would like to know if I can mix `JPA Query creation` with `custom query`, for Example:

```
@Repository
public interface NazioneRepository extends JpaRepository<Nazione, Integer> {

  @Query("select n from Nazione n where n.nome = ?1")
  public List<Nazione> findByActiveTrue(String nome);
}
```

With this I would like to retrieve all the **Nation** with `active` set to `true` and `nome` equals to the String passed as parameter (I tested it but doesn't work).

Maybe in this case I can do something like:

```
public List<Nazione> findByActiveTrueAndNome(String nome);
```

but I'm asking this for more complex case. Can I do this in some way??

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public List<Nazione> findByActiveTrueAndNomeEquals(String nome);
```

or if you want more 'native query':

```
@Query("select n from Nazione n where n.nome = ?1 and active=true")
  public List<Nazione> findByActiveTrue(String nome);
```

you can't mix @Query with auto.

sometimes i used jpa specification (for endpoint with many filters. example:

```
public class NazioneSpec {

    private String nome;

    public Specification<SalesInvoice> getSpecification() {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            query.distinct(true);

            if (nome != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Nazione_.nome), nome));
            }
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Nazione_.active), true));

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }
}
```

and then, u can use:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/nazioneList")
    public List<Nazione> getList(NazioneSpec spec) {
       return repository.findAll(spec.getSpecification());
    }
```

Comment: thank you man! I suppose that @Query will overwrite the wich one created by JPA...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact requirement but I think you can do one thing. You can get all active nation and then sort it by `nome` by using native query like this:

- pass EntityManager to the method and use it after first execution.
- below code is in scala, try to do it in java.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager

def findByActiveTrue(em: EntityManager, nome: String) = {
    val sql = s"select * from Nazione n where n.nome = $nome"
    val value = em.createNativeQuery(sql)
    val result = nativeQuery.getResultList
    result
  }
```

and now you can do anything with the active nations data. check EntityManager's methods in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)